# APT broke my laptop?

Tags: apt, laptop, 19.04

I have Disco Dingo (19.04) and APT said the some packages should be removed. I agree, thinking APT knows what's it's doing. It deleted a few packages such as linux-generic and other linux dependencies. The computer froze. I force-restarted, and upon it booting up, there was no wifi, bluetooth, camera, etc. All of them say "No device detected" or something like that. Do I need a fresh install?

Comment: `apt` follows the rules provided by sources you provide, so I'd take this chance and look at your sources for probably unofficial sources you've added which had package versioning that created the condition, and be careful of them again (unless you're wiling to read the messages before adding/removing packages & assess what it's going to do). The `apt` history (/var/log/apt/) will be useful; including clues possibly on how to fix.  When you force restarted? did you do so using sysrq keys (ie. clean shutdown), if not I'd start by `fsck` your partition (from live) & progress from there...

Comment: All sources are either ubuntu official, or Steam. I force restarted for hold my laptop's power button for 10 seconds.

Comment: Apt doesn't recommend critical removals out of the blue. There is likely more to this story.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it. Thanks for your help. I had to do a fresh install but that's better than spending my weekend working on fixing it. In the end, I found out I had a corrupted boot partition that didn't load in the proper linux modules to use the features that weren't there.